# Cannot convert value of type '(T) -> Void'

Tags: swift, generics, closures

Example:

```
struct Wrapper<T> {
    var key: Int = 0
    var listeners: [Int: (T) -> Void] = Dictionary()

    mutating func add(_ handler:@escaping (T) -> Void) {
        self.key += 1
        self.listeners[self.key] = handler
    }

    func get(key: Int) -> (T) -> Void {
        return self.listeners[key]!
    }
}
```

Test protocol:

```
protocol CommonProtocol {

}
```

Class that create Wrapper of test class

```
class C {
    var wrapper: Wrapper = Wrapper<CommonProtocol>()

    func add<T: CommonProtocol>(_ handler: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        self.wrapper.add(handler) //Cannot convert value of type '(T) -> Void' to expected argument type '(CommonProtocol) -> Void'
    }
}
```

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBj3O.png)

I get error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(T) -> Void' to expected argument type '(CommonProtocol) -> Void'
```

**Question:**

> Why `(T) -> Void` can't be casted to `(CommonProtocol) -> Void` ? The `T`
>   is explicitly declared as `<T: CommonProtocol>`

This is my first question, if you have some suggestions please don't hesitate to contact me

Comment: The compiler is quite correct; a `(T) -> Void` is not a `(CommonProtocol) -> Void`. Let's say `String : CommonProtocol` and `Int : CommonProtocol`. Substitute `String` for `T`. If `(T) -> Void` were convertible to `(CommonProtocol) -> Void`, we could then pass an `Int` into a `String` parameter.

Comment: @Hamish, You are right but, if I change function `add` to this: `func add(_ handler: @escaping (CommonProtocol) -> Void)` I get no error, it looks like if the problem was what you say, this must be an error as well

Comment: Why would you expect that to be an error? You're now passing a `(CommonProtocol) -> Void` to something expecting a `(CommonProtocol) -> Void` – that's totally legal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make `func add` generic.
When you specify in `func add<T: CommonProtocol>...` you explicitly telling the compiler that your function accepts all Types that **inherit** `CommonProtocol` but your Wrapper specifies that accepts `CommonProtocol` not inherited types.

## Solution

Either type-erase class C:

```
Class C<T: CommonProtocol> {
    var wrapper: Wrapper<T>
    ....
}
```

or if type T doesn't actually matter to you then:

```
func add(_ handler: @escaping (CommonProtocol) -> Void)
```

but second one doesn't make sense at all. You have to downcast it every-time you'll use this method (and downcasts are very bad :D)

Note: It's actually not related to this question, but one of your options is to type-erase the `CommonProtocol` too.